# How can I calculate my margin-top in different devices using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive website where in mobile devices the navbar is sticky top and in desktop it isn't sticky top.  Depending on the mobile device's height, some part of the content gets hidden behind the navbar. I need the content to be shown and not hidden behind the navbar.  For this I tried applying a `margin-top` to the content by calculating the height: `margin-top: calc(100vh - 215px);` (my navbar has a height of 215px).  However, this isn't working.  When I add that `margin-top` the content moves way down and it doesn't make sense. (I'm using Bootstrap 4).

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: grey;
    }
    /* Registration Navbar */
    .navbar-searchbar-sticky-top {
        position: fixed;
        height: 215px;
        background-color: red;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 5000;
    }
    /* Content */
    .card-main-container {
        background-color: blue;
        margin-top: calc(100vh - 215px);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-searchbar-sticky-top">
        <nav>
            Nav content here...
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container card-main-container">
        Website content here...
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is my problem in an image:
[image]

By adding `margin-top: calc(100vh - 215px);` I get this:
[image]

This is what I need. The content's margin top to adapt to any device:
[image]

Comment: U can easily do this with JavaScript or jQuery... Or use position sticky in header, not fixed...

Comment: @AtulRajput  Thanks!! Changing `fixed` to `sticky` worked!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Z-index to avoid your stuff to be hidden and you can use percentages rather than pixels

Comment: I don't think that `z-index` is going to help me here since my navbar already has a z-index because it needs to stay over the content. I just need a to add a `margin-top` to my content.